# How to select/group User, startdate and max-date before next the User switch

Tags: sql, sybase

Hard to explain but I'll give my best.

I have a table that stores data when an user scans a badge.

The data that gets stored is the following: **Username, Scan Date, BadgeNr.**

I'll give u an exemple:

`SELECT * FROM scan WHERE badgenr = 'B123';`

```
What I start with:

BadgeNr.           Date         User
B123               01-01-2019   MrOne
B123               02-01-2019   MrOne 
B123               03-01-2019   MrTwo
B123               04-01-2019   MrOne 
B123               05-01-2019   MrThree 
B123               06-01-2019   MrThree

What I am trying to get:

BadgeNr.           Date Start          Date End       User
B123               01-01-2019          02-01-2019     MrOne
B123               03-01-2019          03-01-2019     MrTwo
B123               04-01-2019          04-01-2019     MrOne
B123               05-01-2019          06-01-2019     MrThree
```

As you see the "Date End" isn't really the max date, for that I could use a simple group by and max() and it would be easy... it is the **end date before the next User Switch.**

Is it possible to get what I am expecting?

Comment: a typical gaps and island problem.

Comment: Try looking into analytical functions like Lead and Lag. In your case since you need to compare with the previous record it would be the Lag function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem, which you can solve with a difference of row numbers:

```
select badgenr, user,
       min(date), max(date)
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by badgenr order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by badgenr, user order by date) as seqnum_u
      from scan s
     ) s
group by badgenr, user, (seqnum - seqnum_u);
```